# NSView Does Not Respond To Mouse Events After CABasicAnimation

Tags: cocoa, animation, core-animation, mouseevent

I have a `pageLeft` and `pageRight` animation that animates the position and alpha of 2 views, making a total of 4 simultaneous  `CABasicAnimation`s:

1. Move next page into the view
2. Move current page out of the view
3. Fade in next page
4. Fade out current page

Everything works well with the animations and setup. this question is about mouse events after the page animation. I have found that after the animation runs, the `nextView` **does not** receive `mouseDown:` events. If the animation is not run because the `shouldNotAnimate` block is run below instead, the `nextView` **does** receive `mouseDown:` events.

This means that something about the way I have setup my `CABasicAnimation`s and `CATransaction` is causing this. I am stumped as to what it could be. Any ideas?

---

Animation Code:

```
BOOL forward = currentIndex < index;

if (shouldNotAnimate) {
    // handles swapping pages faster than the animation duration
    [self.sourceViewContainer setSubviews:[NSArray array]];

    [nextView.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [nextView setFrame:self.sourceViewContainer.bounds];
    [nextView.layer setPosition:self.sourceViewContainer.bounds.origin];
    [nextView.layer setOpacity:1.0];
    [self.sourceViewContainer addSubview:nextView];

    [currentView removeFromSuperview];      
    [currentView.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [currentView setFrame:self.sourceViewContainer.bounds];
    [currentView.layer setPosition:self.sourceViewContainer.bounds.origin];
    [currentView.layer setOpacity:1.0];

    self.animationsRunning = NO;

} else {

    self.animationsRunning = YES;

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        self.animationsRunning = NO;
    }];

    // Setup incoming push animation
    [nextView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.sourceViewContainer.bounds.size.width * (forward ? 1 : -1), 0, self.sourceViewContainer.bounds.size.width, self.sourceViewContainer.bounds.size.width)];
    [self.sourceViewContainer addSubview:nextView];
    CABasicAnimation *incomingAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    incomingAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:nextView.frame.origin];
    incomingAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:self.sourceViewContainer.bounds.origin];
    incomingAnimation.duration = PANEL_PAGE_SWIPE_ANIMATION_DURATION;
    incomingAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    incomingAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    incomingAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    incomingAnimation.completion = ^(BOOL finished) {
        [nextView.layer setPosition:self.sourceViewContainer.bounds.origin];
        [nextView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"incoming"];
    };

    [nextView.layer addAnimation:incomingAnimation forKey:@"incoming"];


    // Setup outgoing push animation
    CGRect offscreen = CGRectMake(self.sourceViewContainer.bounds.size.width * (forward ? -1 : 1), 0, self.sourceViewContainer.bounds.size.width, self.sourceViewContainer.bounds.size.height);
    CABasicAnimation *outgoingAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    outgoingAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:self.sourceViewContainer.bounds.origin];
    outgoingAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:offscreen.origin];
    outgoingAnimation.duration = PANEL_PAGE_SWIPE_ANIMATION_DURATION;
    outgoingAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    outgoingAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    outgoingAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    outgoingAnimation.completion = ^(BOOL finished) {
        [currentView removeFromSuperview];
        [currentView.layer setPosition:self.sourceViewContainer.bounds.origin];
        [currentView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"outgoing"];

    };
    [currentView.layer addAnimation:outgoingAnimation forKey:@"outgoing"];


    // Setup incoming alpha animation
    CABasicAnimation *fadeInAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeInAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    fadeInAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    fadeInAnimation.duration = PANEL_PAGE_SWIPE_ANIMATION_DURATION;
    fadeInAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    fadeInAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    fadeInAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    fadeInAnimation.completion = ^(BOOL finished) {
        [nextView.layer setOpacity:1.0f];
        [nextView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"fadeIn"];
    };
    [nextView.layer addAnimation:fadeInAnimation forKey:@"fadeIn"];


    // Setup outgoing alpha animation
    CABasicAnimation *fadeOutAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeOutAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    fadeOutAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    fadeOutAnimation.duration = PANEL_PAGE_SWIPE_ANIMATION_DURATION;
    fadeOutAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    fadeOutAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    fadeOutAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    fadeOutAnimation.completion = ^(BOOL finished) {
        [currentView removeFromSuperview];
        [currentView.layer setOpacity:1.0f];
        [currentView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"fadeOut"];

    };
    [currentView.layer addAnimation:fadeOutAnimation forKey:@"fadeOut"];

    [CATransaction commit];

} // Run animations
```

---

**Solution**

I had to explicitly set the view frame in the completion block, even though I had done this immediately prior to the animation calls.

```
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        self.animationsRunning = NO;
        [nextView setFrame:self.sourceViewContainer.bounds];
    }];
```

Comment: [nextView setFrame:self.sourceViewContainer.bounds]; is the solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what's going on.

CAAnimation objects don't actually change the underlying property that they animation. Instead, it applies the properties to a presentation layer, which is drawn instead of the regular layer. When you create an animation with removedOnCompletion=false, the presentation layer is left active after the animation is completed, but the underlying property still isn't changed. Plus, moving a view's layer doesn't move the view itself, so it won't respond to user interaction at it's new location.

I'd suggest moving your views using UIView block animation (UIView animateWithDuration:completion: and it's relatives) instead of using CAAnimation objects. Those methods actually move the view to it's new position, so that it responds to user interaction at the final location once the animation is complete.

You could do your move and alpha change all in one animation block.

Comment: It maybe a problem with something similar, but this is NSView, not UIView and it is not on iOS. All of the animations are removed in the completion handlers (and the layer frames are also set properly) so I am thinking this is not the problem.

Comment: Even though I had been explicitly setting the nextView frame before this method is called, setting it again to the same value in the CATransaction completion block solved the problem for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, I work in iOS mostly these days. Core Animation with layers is nearly identical on the two platforms. However, Mac OS doesn't have the handy view block animation methods that iOS has (at least not that I know of.) I'm glad you worked it out. EDIT: Upvotes are appreciated for providing a solution...

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with iOS once where the UIMapView because unresponsive after an animation due to a call to the map view. Somehow userInteractionEnable was set to FALSE after the animation finished.

What you could do to test if that is the case is to assert that the value for userInteractionEnable is TRUE.

```
assert(view.userInteractionEnable != FALSE); // ensure user interaction is enabled
```

You may find that when you run the app that it breaks on this assertion. If it does, you can simply set it to TRUE and your app will work as you expect.

As for my issue with UIMapView, the problem went away after an iOS version update so it was likely a bug caused by an edge case. I filed a bug about the problem which may have helped raise awareness about the unexpected behavior.

Comment: This was a good idea the Mac version is acceptsTouchEvents, and it was set to FALSE. I set it to TRUE in the CATransaction completion block, but the problem persists. I then set it for all the nextView subviews in the same place, but the problem persists. I will explore more here, but I think it is something else